# Adicionar variável expect

Tags: script, shell

Gostaria de criar um shell *script* que conecta na controladora *CISCO* para inserir os *macAddres* dos clientes, usando *expect*,  na verdade necessito criar um *script* para automatizar o processo.

Variaveis
**mac_desejado ,descricao**

comando controladora

```
config macfilter add mac_desejado 0 management "descrição"

#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh -l andre 11.111.11.1
expect "password: "
send "PASSWORD\r"
expect "ls\r"
send "exit\r"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
~#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 20
set ip [lindex $argv 0]
set mac [lindex $argv 1]
set desc [lindex $argv 2]



spawn telnet $ip

expect "User:"
send "user\r"

expect "Password:"
send "password\r"


expect ">"
send "config macfilter add $mac 0 management \"$desc\"\r"
expect ">"
send "save config\r"
expect "n)"
send "y\r"
expect ">"
send "exit\r"
```

Comment: Andre não use o campo de Resposta para fazer uma "edição da sua pergunta". Copie o código e edite a sua pergunta original!

Comment: Olá, eu encerrei a pergunta, pesquisei e fiz mais alguns testes e deu certo!